# How to turn on all fields before appending?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I'm using [append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) on model builder, no test schema type. In order that field will match they need to be at the same order, **and visble**. How can I turn on all fields of input layer before appending inside model builder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FieldInfo (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004v000000) documentation:

> Provides field info methods and properties for layer and table views

and describes a method called setVisible to:

> Set the visible flag of a field on the table.

The code sample provided there looks like it will take you 95% of the way on the ArcPy side then you just have to turn it into a Python script tool for you to drag into and then connect within your model.